# No make_table method in Prawn::Document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I have a Rails 3 app that produces PDF documents using Prawn.

In the Gemfile I have:

> gem "prawn", '= 0.12.0'
>
> gem 'prawn-layout'

However, following the example at https://github.com/sandal/prawn/blob/master/examples/table/bill.rb, I am trying to create a table using the make_table method of the Prawn::Document class. This works fine when I run the example on its own, but not when I run the equivalent code in my Rails environment.

Below is the problem in its simplest version in the Rails console. The make_table method is not in the Document object.

Anyone has any hints?

Thanks!

> ruby-1.9.2-p136 :005 > a = Prawn::Document.new  =>
>
> @internal_state=#1 0 R,
>   2=>2 0 R, 3=>3 0 R, 4=>4 0 R, 5=>5 0 R}, @identifiers=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
>   @info=1, @root=2>, @version=1.3,
>   @pages=[#,
>   @margins={:left=>36, :right=>36, :top=>36, :bottom=>36},
>   @stack=#nil,
>   :space=>nil, :phase=>0}, @cap_style=:butt, @join_style=:miter,
>   @line_width=1>]>, @size="LETTER", @layout=:portrait, @content=4,
>   @dictionary=5, @stamp_stream=nil, @stamp_dictionary=nil>],
>   @page=#,
>   @margins={:left=>36, :right=>36, :top=>36, :bottom=>36},
>   @stack=#nil,
>   :space=>nil, :phase=>0}, @cap_style=:butt, @join_style=:miter,
>   @line_width=1>]>, @size="LETTER", @layout=:portrait, @content=4,
>   @dictionary=5, @stamp_stream=nil, @stamp_dictionary=nil>, @trailer={},
>   @compress=false, @encrypt=false, @encryption_key=nil,
>   @optimize_objects=false, @skip_encoding=false,
>   @before_render_callbacks=[], @on_page_create_callback=nil>,
>   @background=nil, @font_size=12,
>   @bounding_box=#, @parent=nil, @x=36,
>   @y=756.0, @height=720.0, @width=540.0, @total_left_padding=0,
>   @total_right_padding=0, @stretched_height=nil>,
>   @margin_box=#, @parent=nil, @x=36,
>   @y=756.0, @height=720.0, @width=540.0, @total_left_padding=0,
>   @total_right_padding=0, @stretched_height=nil>, @page_number=1,
>   @y=756.0>
>
> ruby-1.9.2-p136 :006 > a.methods  => [:bounding_box, :canvas,
>   :column_box, :span, :margin_box, :margin_box=, :margins, :y,
>   :font_size=, :page_number, :page_number=, :state, :page,
>   :start_new_page, :page_count, :go_to_page, :y=, :cursor,
>   :move_cursor_to, :float, :render, :render_file, :bounds,
>   :reference_bounds, :bounds=, :move_up, :move_down, :pad_top,
>   :pad_bottom, :pad, :indent, :mask, :group, :number_pages,
>   :page_match?, :compression_enabled?, :font, :font_size, :set_font,
>   :save_font, :find_font, :font_registry, :font_families, :width_of,
>   :repeaters, :repeat, :outline, :cell, :table, :lazy_bounding_box,
>   :padded_box, :define_grid, :grid, :stamp, :stamp_at, :create_stamp,
>   :image, :move_to, :line_to, :curve_to, :rectangle, :rounded_rectangle,
>   :line_width=, :line_width, :line, :horizontal_line, :horizontal_rule,
>   :vertical_line, :curve, :circle_at, :circle, :ellipse_at, :ellipse,
>   :polygon, :rounded_polygon, :rounded_vertex, :stroke,
>   :close_and_stroke, :stroke_bounds, :fill, :fill_and_stroke,
>   :close_path, :method_missing, :fill_gradient, :stroke_gradient,
>   :rotate, :translate, :scale, :transformation_matrix, :transparent,
>   :join_style, :join_style=, :cap_style, :cap_style=, :dash, :dash=,
>   :undash, :dashed?, :write_stroke_dash, :fill_color, :fill_color=,
>   :stroke_color, :stroke_color=, :text_box, :text, :formatted_text,
>   :draw_text, :height_of, :height_of_formatted, :formatted_text_box,
>   :skip_encoding, :draw_text!, :process_text_options, :default_kerning?,
>   :default_kerning, :default_kerning=, :default_leading,
>   :default_leading=, :text_direction, :text_direction=, :fallback_fonts,
>   :fallback_fonts=, :text_rendering_mode, :character_spacing,
>   :word_spacing, :encrypt_document, :open_graphics_state,
>   :close_graphics_state, :save_graphics_state, :restore_graphics_state,
>   :graphic_stack, :graphic_state, :rollback, :transaction, :dests,
>   :add_dest, :dest_xyz, :dest_fit, :dest_fit_horizontally,
>   :dest_fit_vertically, :dest_fit_rect, :dest_fit_bounds,
>   :dest_fit_bounds_horizontally, :dest_fit_bounds_vertically, :annotate,
>   :text_annotation, :link_annotation, :ref, :ref!, :deref, :add_content,
>   :names, :names?, :before_render, :on_page_create, :taguri=, :taguri,
>   :to_yaml_style, :to_yaml_properties, :syck_to_yaml, :to_yaml, :blank?,
>   :present?, :presence, :acts_like?, :try, :html_safe?, :duplicable?,
>   :`, :returning, :to_param, :to_query, :instance_values,
>   :instance_variable_names, :copy_instance_variables_from, :to_json,
>   :with_options, :as_json, :dclone, :pry, :**binding**,
>   :instance_eval_with_params, :**is_a**, :**metaclass**, :to_matcher,
>   :mocha_inspect, :mocha, :reset_mocha, :stubba_method, :stubba_object,
>   :expects, :stubs, :unstub, :method_exists?, :pretty_print,
>   :pretty_print_cycle, :pretty_print_instance_variables,
>   :pretty_print_inspect, :to_mongo, :require_or_load,
>   :require_dependency, :require_association, :load_dependency, :load,
>   :require, :unloadable, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :<=>,
>   :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :initialize_dup,
>   :initialize_clone, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?,
>   :trust, :freeze, :frozen?, :to_s, :inspect, :methods,
>   :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods,
>   :public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get,
>   :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :instance_of?,
>   :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, :respond_to?,
>   :respond_to_missing?, :extend, :display, :method, :public_method,
>   :define_singleton_method, :**id**, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for,
>   :gem, :silence_warnings, :enable_warnings, :with_warnings,
>   :silence_stderr, :silence_stream, :suppress, :class_eval,
>   :require_library_or_gem, :debugger, :breakpoint, :pretty_inspect,
>   :suppress_warnings, :==, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval,
>   :instance_exec, :**send**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `gem 'prawn-layout'` in your Gemfile. As quoted from https://github.com/sandal/prawn-layout :

> NOTE: prawn-layout has been merged into the main prawn repository as of 2010.02.25 (http://github.com/sandal/prawn), however the stable branch of prawn-layout 0.8.x is still hosted here.

Simply remove `prawn-layout` from your Gemfile and try again.

```
    >> pdf = Prawn::Document.new
    pdf.methods.grep /table/
    => [:table, :make_table]
```